# Is there a simple link from Crucible to the source code on Bitbucket?

Tags: bitbucket-server, atlassian-fisheye, atlassian-crucible

I am using Crucible 4.0.3 and FishEye 4.0.3 to manage code review.
The code is stored in Bitbucket (Stash) 4.0.3.

- Is there a simple link from the review page in Crucible that goes straight to the source code in Bitbucket?

My instance of Crucible is connected to Bitbucket because I can import code from the repository and update the review with edited code; I just can't move seamlessly from Crucible to the code itself in order to make those edits. I can connect seamlessly from Crucible to JIRA and I've checked the instructions given by Atlassian but not found an answer there.

I'm currently working around this by copying the URL of the source code from Bitbucket into the "Details" section on the Crucible review, however I feel there must be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

When you have your review created in Crucible, select a file to display a diff. Now from the "FishEye" drop-down select the "View file source". On this page you will see the "Clone" button which opens a pop-up with a URL to be cloned.

Please note that the "Clone" button may be unavailable if an administrator decided to hide URLs: Administration > Repositories > pick repository > SCM Details tab > Checkout URL option. The "Show URL" must be enabled.